# Creating a new search tab page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, extend

I want to create a new search tab that does the following:
    search some specific text in *.xxx files, BUT the search results in the search results view should be *.yyy files (each *.xxx file has its equivalent *.yyy)

I extended `org.eclipse.search.searchPages` and created my own search page that implements `performAction()`. This method basically does:

```
NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(newQuery());
```

and `newQuery()` method delegates on `TextSearchQueryProvider` as follows

```
TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred().createQuery(input);
```

The problem is that I don't want to show the files found by the textSearchQueryProvider in the results view. How can I force another results ?

I would appreciate any article explaining in detail how to develop a new search class and how to display the search results.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to show your results? You can customize your search result view by using the extension `org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages`